# What's the order of this algorithm in Big-O notation (string permutations)?

Tags: c, string, performance, big-o, permutation

What is the performance in Big-O notation of the following algorithm? 
It's a function I wrote to print all permutations of a string.
I know for an input of length n there are n! different permutations.
Can somebody provide an explanation of the analysis made to reach such conclusions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void permute(char* output, char* input, int used[], int index, int length){
    int i;

    if (index == length) {
        printf("%s\n", output);
        return;
    }

    for (i=0; i< length; i++){
        if (! used[i] ){
            output[index] = input[i];
            used[i] = 1;
            permute(output, input, used, index+1, length);
            used[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}


int main(){
    char input[] = "abcd";
    char* output;
    int length = strlen(input);
    int* used;

    // Allocate space for used array
    used = (int*) malloc (sizeof (int)* length);
    memset (used, 0, sizeof (int)* length);

    // Allocate output buffer
    output = (char*) malloc ( length+1);
    if (!output) return 1;
    output[length] = '\0';

    // First recursive call
    permute(output, input, used, 0, length);

    free (output);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For the ultimate explanations have a look at Knuth, Vol 4A: Generating all permutations.

Comment: Dont use recursive method. Try to convert to iterative one. Otherwise you'll soon face **stack overflow**.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im If you use tail-recursive functions, this virtually does not matter as good compilers can optimize this case.

Comment: @FUZxxl then you have to find a *good* compiler. BTW is this function *tail-recursive*?

Comment: @cxxl The specific section is 7.2.1.2 on page 319. His algorithm L gives an easy method to generate all permutations of a given integer sequence a_1, a_2, ..., a_n in lexicographic order. He also gives a faster algorithm P that interchanges only one pair between two successing permutations.

Answer (score 4):

> I know for an input of length n there are n! different permutations.

You just answered your own question

Comment: Well, his implementation could have been worse than O(n!). :)

Comment: It is indeed not n!. n! are just the number of recursive calls that actually finish a permutation and print it, but not all of the recursive calls do so.

Comment: n! is the number of calls in last step only. Total number of calls are: `n + n*(n-1) + n*(n-1)*(n-2) + ... n!`

Answer (score 1):

I would say O(n!), since every recursion does a loop with n rounds and calls something on an object of "size" n-1 (since used[i] has masked out one character).